# Can we copy Microsoft Edge tab groups from one PC to another?

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-edge

I've just got a new PC, and want to copy my Edge tab groups from my old one. I had about 120 tabs open, arranged in about 15 groups, and it would be a major pain to have to set all tat up again.

I've searched around, but haven't yet found a decent solution. Anyone any ideas? Seems like such an obvious thing to want to do.

Comment: If you have a Microsoft account it's trivial. It works the same way in Chrome with a Google account or in Firefox with a Mozilla account.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Please can you explain a bit more. As far as I could see, having a MS account just means that you can click on "Tabs from other devices" and see what tabs are open there. I'd still have to open each one individually, then create tab groups and assign the tabs to the groups. This is al very slow and painful. I was expecting the ability to export my tabs en masse, and just import them into the new PC, and end up with all my tabs in the right groups. Maybe I missed something, but I couldn't see how to that, even with an MS account. Thanks

Comment: You can have all your profile settings including bookmarks, etc. etc. by sync'ing with the online accounts. It has been the norm for many years now.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I signed in on my old device and made sure sync was on. I also checked in the profile settings that it's supposed to sync open tabs. I then went to another device, started Edge and signed in, but I can't see how to load the tabs that are open on the first device. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: @ChanganAuto Just to clarify, if I go to History and click "Tabs from other devices" I can see the tabs, but as I explained before, this means I need to click each one in turn, then create groups and add the tabs to the groups. Isn't there a way of just importing all my tabs and groups in one go?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm sure syncing your data is supposed to help, but it didn't strike me as being anywhere near a decent solution for what I would have thought would have been a very basic requirement.

I solved the problem without too much effort by installing [this add-in](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/save-all-tab-urls/djbejkhoeddlhcimemncgmmfbdkifkim), which opens a new tab, and lists the URLs of all open tabs. I then copied the contents of this into a text file and saved it somewhere where I could get at it on my new PC.

On the new PC, I used [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) (which I have anyway, but you can use for free and then remove if you only want to use it this once), set the Language to `C# Statements` and pasted the following code in...

```
var psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\tabs.txt").ToList().ForEach(f =>
{
    psi.FileName = f;
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
});
```

You'll need to change `D:\tabs.txt` to point at the file you saved earlier.

Hit f5 to run the script, and all of your tabs should open in your default browser.

If there are any errors (which I had as I had a couple of PDFs open in Edge, which weren't copied to the new PC), these will be reported in LinqPad.

After that I had to create tab groups and move each tab into its appropriate group. This was a bit of a pain, but as the tabs opened in the same order as they had been on the other PC, it didn't take too long.

Not an ideal solution, but until Microsoft realise that some people might actually want to copy their tab data to another machine, and that syncing just doesn't do the job, this is the best I could find.